# Convert Firebase Data Object to Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, firebase-realtime-database

I get from Firebase Realtime Database data by `task.getResult().getValue()`. It looks like:

```
{
    jyIibta0UWaRF2={Name=Value1, Surname=Value2},
    Oy8r5SEYacKKM2={Name=Value3, Surname=Value4}
}
```

How can I convert it to Array. So I can find an item by its index.
Like:

```
data[1][1]; //Must return "Surname=Value4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the object to an array, you could do something like this:

```js
const obj = {
    jyIibta0UWaRF2: {Name: "Value1", Surname: "Value2"},
    Oy8r5SEYacKKM2: {Name: "Value3", Surname: "Value4"}
}

let data = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  data.push(["Name="+obj[key].Name, "Surname="+obj[key].Surname]);
});

console.log(data[1][1]);
```

---

But since you mention this comes from Firebase Realtime Database, I recommend learning to navigate the `DataSnapshot` class from there. Given a `snapshot` with the structure you show, you can navigate it with:

```
for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
    Log.d("Firebase", child.getKey()); // "jyIibta0UWaRF2", "Oy8r5SEYacKKM2"
    Log.d("Firebsae", child.child("Surname").getValue(String.class); // "Value2", "Value4"
}
```

This uses the two ways to navigate data in a `DataSnapshot`:

- If you don't know the key of what you need, you can loop over all children/properties with `getChildren()`.
- If you know the key/name of what you need, you can access it with `child(...)`.

And to retrieve data:

- Call `getValue(...)` with the type of data of the property (a `String.class` in this case.